# C error with pointer and const char[]

Tags: c, pointers

I have a const char arr[] parameter that I am trying to iterate over,

```
char *ptr;
for (ptr= arr; *ptr!= '\0'; ptr++) 
  /* some code*/
```

I get an error: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Are const char [] handled differently than non-const?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Switch the declaration of *ptr to be.

```
const char* ptr;
```

The problem is you are essentially assigning a const char* to a char*.  This is a violation of const since you're going from a const to a non-const.

Answer (score 10):

As JaredPar said, change ptr's declaration to

```
const char* ptr;
```

And it should work.  Although it looks surprising (how can you iterate a const pointer?), you're actually saying the pointed-to character is const, not the pointer itself.  In fact, there are two different places you can apply const (and/or volatile) in a pointer declaration, with each of the 4 permutations having a slightly different meaning.  Here are the options:

```
char* ptr;              // Both pointer & pointed-to value are non-const
const char* ptr;        // Pointed-to value is const, pointer is non-const 
char* const ptr;        // Pointed-to value is non-const, pointer is const
const char* const ptr;  // Both pointer & pointed-to value are const.
```

Somebody (I think Scott Meyers) said you should read pointer declarations inside out, i.e.:

```
const char* const ptr;
```

...would be read as "ptr is a constant pointer to a character that is constant".

Good luck!

Drew

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Now I just have to remember what it means when the method is marked as const...

Answer (score 0):

The const declaration grabs whatever is to the left. If there is nothing it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

For interation loops like the above where you don't care about the value returned you should say `++ptr` rather than `ptr++`.

`ptr++` means:

```
temp = *ptr;
++ptr;
return temp;`
```

`++ptr` means:

```
++ptr;
return *ptr;
```

For the primitive types, the compiler will apply this optimization but won't when iterating over C++ objects so you should get in the habit of writing it the right way.